# Compositing in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, compositing

Is there any compositing built in Lubuntu? I do not mean installing compiz but rather something simple like Metacity compositing to satisfy apps that require it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

LXDE is by design a light-weight graphical environment with no direct composite manager.

Lubuntu does have the X composite extensions built in though with allows you to install a composite manager of your choice, for example

1. xcompmgr - a basic lightweight composite manager with a few effects such as shadows and translucent windows. Works with Cairo or Docky. N.B. don't forget to add xcompmgr as part of your autostart programs on logon.
2. metacity - the standard software based composite manager for basic graphics cards
3. compiz - the fully fledged all singing all dancing wobbly effects composite manager requiring a more modern graphics card.

Cairo with xcompmgr in Lubuntu:

[image]

From ubuntu community help:

> Compiz and Cairo are two rather heavyweight solutions with lots of
>   resource-heavy eyecandy. An alternative consistent with the small
>   footprint of Lubuntu is xcompmgr.

xcompmgr installation:

```
sudo apt-get install xcompmgr

leafpad ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

add line

```
@xcompmgr -c
```

Source:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Windows#How_to_control_window_opacity 
 [[SOLVED] How to enable compositing in Lubuntu.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1856701)