# Docky lubuntu autohide issue

Tags: lubuntu, docky

I installed lunbutu 13.04 with docky and when i open windows the dock is not hiding.
I tried to enable auto hiding in dock setting but will not let me change the setting,also i can't change to 3d dock.Every time i enter docky it say that composititng is not enabled.

Any way to enable compositing or at least fix autohide THX

Comment: Did you install `dockmanager` as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`gconf-editor` [image: Install gconf-editor]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gconf-editor) to change Metacity options in `apps/metacity/general`

You need to tick `compositing_manager` and possibly `compositor_effects`. That works for me. You can read more about compositing here: [Compositing in Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53745/compositing-in-lubuntu)