# Chrome 38 displaying weird colors and Fonts ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: graphics, google-chrome, display, fonts, colors

I have updated google chrome from 34 to 38 stable version by downloading .deb from their official website. After the update chrome is giving weird Display.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS . This colour display problem only happened after update and rest of applications like Firefox is displaying properly.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the theme in the settings - you could also try enabling [compositing in Lubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53745/compositing-in-lubuntu), though this might not work on older hardware.

Comment: @Wilf i forget to mention, i am using it on Lubuntu Desktop, Now i tried switiching to Ubuntu, But still bug persists. http://i.imgur.com/JaUXF5e.png and changing theme also doesnt help.  will installing metacity will help ?

Comment: Might do - though I think Unity uses compiz and lxde uses openbosx or something - what graphics hardware and drivers are you using (use `lspci -v`).

Comment: its quite an old system running intel 82801 graphics card, Thats why i asked for Metacity.

Comment: I also tried installing google chrome Version 36.0.1985.143 now, and is giving same issue, However google chrome 34 works fine , There must be something more to it

Comment: Do any error occur when running google chrome from terminal? (you can [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/544393/edit) this into your question)